# Programmatically creating nodes with audiofield in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

How do I create audiofield (formfield as audio widget) content programmatically?

Specifically how I do "import" file contents (in this case MP3 files).

I tried node import module but does not seem to work properly.

This is Drupal 6 implementation.

Thanks,

Murali

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question.  If you would like to upload an mp3 file to a cck node, you can use the filefield module.

- create a new cck node-type
- add a filefield to this nodetype, and select 'file' as the field type.
- Configure this filefield:  Under "Permitted upload file extensions", enter "mp3".
  Under "number of values", selected "unlimited" if you would like to upload an arbitrary number of mp3 files.

Once you define your node-type, you can programatically create a node with node_save().  See here: http://drupal.org/node/1111514